# Copy string text, and paste it in 6 input text boxes, showing the full string on first box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question regarding copy and pasting a string such as "123456", in 6 different input text fields. The input text fields have also have maxlength as 1, I first had to remove this attribute from the fields for it to paste the whole 6 characters in each input field. The solution I have right now works, but I am having a slight problem, because as soon as I paste the whole 6 number digit on the first box, it puts the whole string on the first box for a small amount of time, and then it puts the numbers on the other fields. The question is, how can I do to not see the whole number being pasted on the first box, and showing only one number? Here is a working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Heading Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <input type="text" name="numberInput" value="" tab-index="0" placeholder="#" maxlength="1">
    <input type="text" name="numberInput" value="" tab-index="1" placeholder="#" maxlength="1">
    <input type="text" name="numberInput" value="" tab-index="2" placeholder="#" maxlength="1">
    <input type="text" name="numberInput" value="" tab-index="3" placeholder="#" maxlength="1">
    <input type="text" name="numberInput" value="" tab-index="4" placeholder="#" maxlength="1">
    <input type="text" name="numberInput" value="" tab-index="5" placeholder="#" maxlength="1">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="text"]').bind('paste', function() {
            var self = this,
                textArray;

            // Short pause to wait for paste to complete, remove attribute for it to paste the 6 digits into the text boxes
            $('input[type="text"]').removeAttr('maxlength');
            setTimeout( function() {
                textArray = $(self).val().split('');
                $('input[type="text"]').each(function(index,element){
                  $(element).val(textArray[index]);
                  $(element).attr('maxlength','1');
                });
            }, 100,function(){
                //Do some action needed
            });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: would have worked just removing the delay in setTimeout also

Comment: I am sorry how come? I just tested it without the setTimeout and it only pastes the first character on the first textbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the properties of the `paste` event to prevent the default action and get the intended paste text, and then do your logic, removing the `setTimeout` as well since you are not using the native paste event anymore.

Also, there is no need to remove and add the `maxlength` attribute that I can see- you are only inserting one character anyway, and since we are bypassing the native paste event, the full string never *really* hits any of the inputs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Heading Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <input type="text" name="numberInput" value="" tab-index="0" placeholder="#" maxlength="1">
    <input type="text" name="numberInput" value="" tab-index="1" placeholder="#" maxlength="1">
    <input type="text" name="numberInput" value="" tab-index="2" placeholder="#" maxlength="1">
    <input type="text" name="numberInput" value="" tab-index="3" placeholder="#" maxlength="1">
    <input type="text" name="numberInput" value="" tab-index="4" placeholder="#" maxlength="1">
    <input type="text" name="numberInput" value="" tab-index="5" placeholder="#" maxlength="1">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="text"]').bind('paste', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
          var textArray = text.split('');

          $('input[type="text"]').each(function(index,element){
            $(element).val(textArray[index]);
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No problem- note too that I edited slightly to remove the code for removing and adding `maxlength`, I don't think it is needed.